# Speeding up face landmark detector

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, dlib

I had build a mex function of dlib's face landmark detection example. As an input parameter example takes path to `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`.

I would like instead to open `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` in Matlab and pass it as a parameter to `mex_function` and not open it every time I call mex function (code posted below takes 2 seconds).

Since I am a beginner to cpp and dlib I don't know how to implement this or if this is the right approach.

Any help is highly appreciated !

```
void mex_function (const string shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks_location, const array2d<rgb_pixel>&img ,matlab_struct& output){

    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();

    shape_predictor sp;
    deserialize(shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks_location) >> sp;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That code is not valid `mex` nor `cpp`

Comment: Code pasted above works in matlab after I build mex file.  [Here](https://paste.ofcode.org/SxLzaYQLjWpAUFsCZBG7X8) is the whole code.

Comment: I am surprised, as all mex fucntions have the same "main" `void mexFunction(int  nlhs , mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, mxArray const *prhs[])`

Comment: I found out that the difference is due to mex_wrapper.cpp that dlib provides. [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davisking/dlib/master/dlib/matlab/example_mex_function.cpp) is more detailed explanation.